# Python Try Except stopping program as opposed to skipping over errror

Tags: python, try-catch

I am running a sequence of scripts that are independent of each other. Meaning if one of them fails I want the rest to continue on and just be notified of the one that failed(I can implement the notification later). For now I am just trying to figure out why the program is not continuing on.

I am trying doing a test in which I have the sequence. However Script 2 in this case has an error as there is not a file its trying to read in. I am getting

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

And the program is stopping.

```
def errorFunction(function, name):
    print('Running Script: ' + name)
    try:
        function
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('FileNotFound Error. Script Name ' + name)
    except:
        print('Error. Script Name ' + name)
        pass

errorFunction(Script1(), 'Script1')
errorFunction(Script2(), 'Script2')
errorFunction(Script3(), 'Script3')
```

Comment: You're calling the functions *before* calling `errorFunction` on their output, so of course the error can't be caught. You function should contain `try: function()` (mind the parentheses to call it at this point), and you have to use it like this: `errorFunction(Script1, 'Script1')` (mind the absence of parentheses - you pass the function, not its output)

Comment: What about calling `os.path.exists()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
errorFunction(Script1(), 'Script1')
```

This is your problem.  Since there are parentheses on the end of `Script1()`, you are *actually calling* that function here, before `errorFunction()` even executes.

Take off the parentheses here, like so:

```
errorFunction(Script1, 'Script1')
```

And then add parentheses here, like so:

```
try:
    function()
```